# Adding a custom title to a fixed-style table of contents in using rmd / knitr

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr, tableofcontents

I am having problems trying to do something simple. I am creating a HTML file using Rmarkdown/knitr, in which I want to have a fixed TOC (table of content). For that, I modified a .css file in order to include several options:

```
#TOC {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #eaf9ff;
  font: 15.5px arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #000000;
}
```

And, in the Rmd I am using the following options:

```
---
title: "Intro"
author: "ME"
output:
  html_document:
    css: camo.css
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 7
    fig_width: 9
    highlight: zenburn
    theme: readable
    toc: yes
fontsize: 11.5pt
urlcolor: blue
editor_options: 

  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

These options create a fixed table of contents that is link to my HTML file, but it does not include a title for the table of contents. I just want to add/personalize a title, something like: "List of contents" or something, but I am not sure how to do it... Any help will be great.